# How is this ATR indicator able to avoid repainting even with security function?

Tags: pine-script

I have had serious problems with repainting EMA type indicators, smoother filters, etc where I get 2 minute or 2 candle delays and redundancies of that sort both with and without security function; however security function causes more repainting. However, I have an ATR indicator that I added security function to and it does *not* repaint under any circumstances and it does not lag two candles, only a normal open on the following candle with close on confirm.

````
```pine-script
//@version=3
// Copyright (c) 2019-present, Alex Orekhov (everget)
// SuperTrend script may be freely distributed under the terms of the GPL- 
3.0 license.
study("SuperTrend", overlay=true)

length = input(title="ATR Period", type=integer, defval=22)
mult = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)
showLabels = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Labels ?", type=bool, defval=true)
src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
timeFrame = input(title="Other time frame", type=string, defval="3")


atr = 0.0
atr := nz(atr[1]) + (src - (nz(atr[1]) + nz(atr[length])) / 2) / length 
////////////



// Retrieve the higher time frame's data





longStopPrev = nz(atr[1], atr)
atr := close[1] > longStopPrev ? max(atr, longStopPrev) : atr


shortStopPrev = nz(atr[1], atr)
atr := close[1] < shortStopPrev ? min(atr, shortStopPrev) : atr

dir = 1
dir := nz(dir[1], dir)
dir := dir == -1 and close > shortStopPrev ? 1 : dir == 1 and close < 
longStopPrev ? -1 : dir

longColor = green
shortColor = red

plot(dir == 1 ? atr : na, title="Long Stop", style=linebr, linewidth=2, 
color=longColor)
buySignal = dir == 1 and dir[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? atr : na, title="Long Stop Start", 
location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, 
color=longColor, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showLabels ? atr : na, title="Buy Label", 
text="Buy", location=location.bottom, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, 
color=longColor, textcolor=white, transp=0)

plot(dir == 1 ? na : atr, title="Short Stop", style=linebr, linewidth=2, 
color=shortColor)
sellSignal = dir == -1 and dir[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? atr : na, title="Short Stop Start", 
location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, 
color=shortColor, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showLabels ? atr : na, title="Sell Label", 
text="Sell", location=location.top, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, 
color=shortColor, textcolor=white, transp=0)
```
````

Comment: Hi, If you expect help with code, then you should supply a properly formatted (using code tags), self-standing snippet that compiles. Note that in order to achieve this, it is also important to include the `//@version=` compiler directive at the top.

Comment: I'm struggling to use the correct syntax identifier in the editor to highlight pinescript such as  <!-- language: lang-pine -->

Comment: Also, in regard to the OP, what I have discovered is causing the two candle delays I believe is that I have a stack of indicators sourcing each other, one EMA sourcing another EMA, a nest of usually 3 or 4. As soon as I add the third, I get the redundancy, if it's just one ema on another it will avoid the issue.

Comment: could you also add to code how you use security with `atr` and `ema`?